# Java MongoDB: What is the difference between com.mongodb.DB and com.mongodb.client

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new using MongoDB, I'm working in a Java project and I started some tutorials to start working with the Driver.

I was using `com.mongodb.client` until I noticed that there was no findOne method in the `com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection` so I rewrited my project to use only `com.mongodb.DB` and the `DBCollection` library includes the findOne method which I need.

I was wondering what is the difference between those two libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`com.mongodb.DB` is the old API for accessing Mongo before 3.x. You will find plenty of tutorials for those classes. The code is fully functional and you can use it for accessing Mongo 2.x and Mongo 3.x databases but it is not recommended to start a new project using it.

Since 3.0 the recommended way is via  `com.mongodb.MongoClient` and `com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase`. See the [official tutorial of the Java driver here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/client/).

Comment: Can com.mongodb.MongoClient and com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase still be used with MongoDB versions 2.x?

Comment: From my point of view the different APIs differ only how the queries are built on client side, but the used server APi is more or less the same. Therefore it should work. Also the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/#java-driver-compatibility) does not mention anything negative in that direction.